# How come Harrow didn't get ceremonial armour?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, moon-knight-2022

In *Moon Knight*, we see that Marc, Steven and Layla all get ceremonial armour of different kinds (Moon Knight, Mr Knight, Scarlet Scarab) when they become their gods' avatars. The armour has been shown to be strongly protective multiple times.

But when Harrow became Ammit's avatar, he remained in the maroon pyjamas that he wore for most of the series.

Harrow would definitely have found some protective and/or healing armour useful in the battle against Steven/Marc* and Layla. So why didn't Ammit grant him ceremonial armour?

*

> /Jake

Comment: It’s just another example of the constant discrimination against white men just because they dare to defy political correctness and say what we’re all thinking, i.e. that 80% of humanity should be fed to a giant crocodile god.

Comment: Harrow does have that cane/ax. He had it before becoming an official avatar, but it did get powered up when he did sign on. As someone who is into self-harm, it makes sense that Ammit's favor wouldn't manifest as armor for him. Hoping who has read the comics could say whether is supported by evidence and could post it as an answer.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Be truthful, are you the new avatar of Ammit ?

Comment: @user96551 if I lie that probably wouldn’t be good for the scales, so… no?

Answer (score 21):

The suits are granted to the avatars through the power of their respective gods. However, there has to be a willingness to wear the suit. We see multiple times that the suit doesn't just come to the avatar and that the avatar has to willingly summon it. This is made most clear in episode 2 when Steven needs to summon the suit and doesn't know how to, Khonshu is unable to summon it for him.

> **Khonshu:** There is no deal in this, Marc. Fix this. Fix this! Summon the suit.
>
> **Steven:** Sorry, what?
>
> **Khonshu:** Summon the suit.
>
> **Steven:** "Summon the soup"? What are you saying?
>
> **Khonshu:** The suit. Summon it.
>
> <sub>*Moon Knight*, Season 1 Episode 2, "Summon the Suit"</sub>

Given that Harrow's whole persona is a man of repentance who is bringing about a godly duty of "fair" judgement to people, it's possible he didn't want to summon the suit. It doesn't exactly fit with his whole schtick. Some armour would work directly against his cause. Even before becoming Ammit's official avatar, he doesn't walk around in armour/protective clothing in places where he probably should do.

It's worth noting the scene where we're introduced to Harrow as well: the glass in the shoes, the way the townspeople treat him. He is a prophet to the followers of Ammit and he dresses and acts accordingly.

Lastly, it is pointed out in episode 2 that Khonshu's avatar's armour comes from Khonshu's temple. It's possible that when Ammit was imprisoned and banished, her temple was also destroyed and that any ceremonial armour she did have for her avatars was destroyed; or the ability to summon it was lost.

> **Marc:** Oy, Steven, what the hell are we wearing?
>
> **Steven:** I don't know. She said I needed a suit.
>
> **Marc:** Yeah, the ceremonial armour from Khonshu's temple, not psycho Colonel Sanders.
>
> **Steven:** Well, I don't know how any of this shit works, man.
>
> <sub>*Moon Knight*, Season 1 Episode 2, "Summon the Suit"</sub>

Prompted by [@Harabeck's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263125/how-come-harrow-didnt-get-ceremonial-armour/263128#comment725244_263125) on the question I remembered that Harrow's cane does contain some of Ammit's power. When Harrow is explaining this he also says it was a gift to her first avatar. This doesn't mean that her avatars can't have armour and the cane but does show that she doesn't exactly leave Harrow completely defenceless.

> **Harrow:** Do you know what this is?
>
> **Steven:** Yep. It's a cane, yeah.
>
> **Harrow:** This is... Ammit's gift to her first Avatar.
>
> **Steven:** All right.
>
> **Harrow:** It contains in it a tiny sliver of her power.
>
> <sub>*Moon Knight*, Season 1 Episode 2, "Summon the Suit"</sub>